# In Corda,Please tell me how to add a Node without building

Tags: corda

I added Node by the following procedure.
PartyD started, but it was recognized as PartyC.
Please tell me how to start PartyD properly without rebuild. 
 Assuming that many people use Corda node to create a network, it is not a good idea to rebuild CordaApp and distribute it every time one participates in the network. Therefore, I think that there should be a method to add without building.

**[procedure]**

> 1. Run [.gradlew clean deploynodes] on Corda-example (V2).
> 2. Go to [./ java-source / build / nodes], copy the [PartyC] directory and create it as [PartyD]
> 3. Changed each Port of [PartyD's [node.conf] so that it does not overlap with other Nodes
> 4. In addition, change [myLegalName = "O = PartyC, L = Paris, C = FR"] of [Party D [node.conf]] to [myLegalName = "O = PartyD, L = Tokyo, C =
>      JP"].
> 5. Run [runnodes].
> 6. If you access the Port of [Party D] from the browser and click on WebAPI [me], [myLegalName = "O = PartyC, L = Paris, C = FR"] is
>      displayed.
>
> The expected value was [myLegalName = "O = PartyD, L = Tokyo, C =
>   JP"].

**[Question]**

1. Why is it not recognized as PartyD?
2. Please tell me the correct procedure to add Node without building.

Comment: Are you able to upgrade to V3? If so, take a look at this blog post for how the network map now works.
https://medium.com/corda/re-designing-the-network-map-760f62ae8c62

Answer (score 1):

The procedure you describe works fine for me on Corda 2. The party is correctly identified as `PartyD`.

I suspect that you had started the `PartyC` node before copying its folder. Make sure you delete the `artemis`, `certificates` and `persistence.mv.db` to reset it. In particular, the `certificates` folder will contain auto-generated certificates bearing `PartyC`'s name.

Comment: Thanks Joel.
In the way you taught, PartyD got to be recognized correctly.
However, when accessing the Party A website and calling the Peers API, Party D was not recognized.
What is this?
I am using the example of Corda-V3.